# how to launch default map application to select a location in cordova app

Tags: android, ios, cordova, maps, hybrid-mobile-app

I am creating a Cordova app, and I want to have a button or a link when clicked it opens the default map application of the device, and select a location from it. then bring back the coordinates to my Cordova app. How to achieve this?

Comment: You will need to display the map view in your app and interact with it in your own code. While you can open the maps application on the device, there is no method for the map application to return a location to an app

Answer (score 0):

You can either [use a plugin for navigation](https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-launch-navigator) or implement the solutions provided by gist below.

https://gist.github.com/danharper/844382901f7a7b73b90a